# Angular 8 Jasmine and karma testing: mocked ngonit promise value is not rendered in the DOM

Tags: javascript, angular, testing, jasmine, karma-runner

My mock data in a test will not display in the markup when running the test. No matter what i try (fakeasync, done, stubs) the content of the promise is not rendered in the markup after running the test.

Can anyone please tell me why this mocked promise data will not display in the dom. I have spent 2 days almost on this and it simply does not work no matter what i try. I'm using angular 8 and starting to think it's a bug in the framework.

I have the following markup:

```
<div>
    <div class="pt-8">
        <!-- Displays -->
        <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let worker of workers">{{worker.getName()}}</li>
        </ul>

        <!-- DOES NOT DISPLAY -->
        <ol>
            <li *ngFor="let centre of centres">{{centre.name}}</li>
        </ol>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the class:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { WorkcentersService } from 'app/services/workcenters.service';
import { Workcenter } from 'app/model/workcenter';
import { User } from 'app/model/user';

@Component({
  selector: 'test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.scss']
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
  workers: User[];
  centres: Workcenter[];

  constructor(private workcentersService: WorkcentersService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    let user1 = new User(); user1.name = "worker 1"; user1.surname = "surname1";
    let user2 = new User(); user2.name = "worker 2"; user2.surname = "surname2";
    let user3 = new User(); user3.name = "worker 3"; user3.surname = "surname3";
    this.workers = [user1, user2, user3];
    this.workcentersService.getWorkcentersList().then(wc => this.centres = wc);
  }
}
```

This is the test:

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed, fakeAsync, tick } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { WorkcentersService } from 'app/services/workcenters.service';
import { Workcenter } from 'app/model/workcenter';
import { TestComponent } from './test.component';

fdescribe('TestComponent', () => {
  let component: TestComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestComponent>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const mockCentres = createMockCentres();
    const mockWorkcentersService = jasmine.createSpyObj(["getWorkcentersList"]);
    mockWorkcentersService.getWorkcentersList.and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(mockCentres));

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [TestComponent],
      imports: [],
      providers: [
        { provide: WorkcentersService, useValue: mockWorkcentersService }
      ]
    });

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    await fixture.whenStable();
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  // Passes
  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  // Passes
  it('should render users', async () => {
    const displayedUsers = fixture.nativeElement.querySelectorAll("ul li");
    expect(displayedUsers.length).toEqual(3);
  });

  // Fails
  it('should render centres', async () => {
    const displayedUsers = fixture.nativeElement.querySelectorAll("ol li");
    expect(displayedUsers.length).toEqual(2);
  });

  // Fails
  it('should display "hello"', fakeAsync(() => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    tick();
    const displayedUsers = fixture.nativeElement.querySelectorAll("ol li");
    expect(displayedUsers.length).toEqual(2);
  }));

  function createMockCentres(): Workcenter[] {
    const mockCentre1 = new Workcenter();mockCentre1.id = 1;mockCentre1.name = "Test centre 1";
    const mockCentre2 = new Workcenter();mockCentre2.id = 2;mockCentre2.name = "Test centre 2";
    return [mockCentre1, mockCentre2];
  }
});
```

Comment: in which test case you expect it to appear? is you test case failing?

Comment: in test "should render centres". However it should render in all of them really.

Comment: change it of one of the testcases to fit, see if it renders?

Comment: What do u mean? it doesn't render for any of them.

Comment: try my solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import { ComponentFixture, fakeAsync, TestBed, tick } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { WorkCenter } from './workCenter';
import { WorkcentersService } from './workcenters.service';

fdescribe('TestComponent', () => {
  let component: AppComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;
  let mockWorkcentersService: WorkcentersService;
  beforeEach(async () => {
    const mockCentres = createMockCentres();
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [AppComponent],
      imports: [],
      providers: [
        WorkcentersService
      ]
    });

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    mockWorkcentersService = TestBed.get(WorkcentersService);
    spyOn(mockWorkcentersService, 'getWorkcentersList').and.returnValue(new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve(mockCentres)));
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    await fixture.whenStable();
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  // Passes
  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  // Passes
  it('should render users', async () => {
    const displayedUsers = fixture.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('ul li');
    expect(displayedUsers.length).toEqual(3);
  });

  // Fails
  it('should render centres', async () => {
    expect(mockWorkcentersService.getWorkcentersList).toHaveBeenCalled();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    await fixture.whenStable();
    const displayedUsers = fixture.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('ol li');
    expect(displayedUsers.length).toEqual(2);
  });

  // Fails
  it('should display "hello"', fakeAsync(() => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    tick();
    const displayedUsers = fixture.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('ol li');
    expect(displayedUsers.length).toEqual(2);
  }));

  function createMockCentres(): WorkCenter[] {
    const mockCentre1 = new WorkCenter(); mockCentre1.id = 1; mockCentre1.name = 'Test centre 1';
    const mockCentre2 = new WorkCenter(); mockCentre2.id = 2; mockCentre2.name = 'Test centre 2';
    return [mockCentre1, mockCentre2];
  }
});
```

This worked for me

proof :-

[image]

Also tried running single test case to show you that test centers are displaying now :-

[image]

Comment: This doesn't compile. Where is mockWorkcentersService instantiated? Also how will you replace WorkcentersService with the mock?

Comment: But you're still not declaring mockWorkcentersService so code doesn't compile

Comment: try now, if it doesn't work try getting service from fixture.injector

Comment: @AndyKing did you check it?

Comment: It doesn't work. mockWorkcentersService = TestBed.get(WorkcentersService); returns undefined

Comment: can you try moving that statement after createComponent?

Comment: Still doesn't work.Error: <spyOn> : could not find an object to spy upon for getWorkcentersList()
Usage: spyOn(<object>, <methodName>). Can you try it at your end and update post

Answer (score 0):

@Aakash Garg Ive accepted your answer as you got it right.

After spending (yet) more time on this I found that the fact we created spies differently didn't make any difference.

The key fact was you turned around 
fixture.detectChanges();
await fixture.whenStable();
I had them the other way around.

Also you added a fixture.detectChanges() in the test itself which was also necessary. The additonal whenStable call didn't seem to make any difference.

In the end I used fixture.autoDetectChanges() which made it work without the fixture.whenStable call as below:

```
beforeEach(async () => {
    const mockCentres = createMockCentres();
    const workers = { workers: createMockWorkers(), companyId: 22 };
    const mockWorkcentersService = jasmine.createSpyObj(["getWorkcentersList"]);
    mockWorkcentersService.getWorkcentersList.and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(mockCentres));

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [CentreAssociateComponent],
      imports: [],
      providers: [
        //WorkcentersService,
        { provide: WorkcentersService, useValue: mockWorkcentersService },
        { provide: MAT_DIALOG_DATA, useValue: workers },
        { provide: MatDialogRef, useValue: {} }
      ]
    });

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CentreAssociateComponent);
    fixture.autoDetectChanges();
    component = fixture.componentInstance;

    await fixture.whenStable();
  });

  it('should render centres', async () => {
    const displayedUsers = fixture.nativeElement.querySelectorAll("ol li");
    expect(displayedUsers.length).toEqual(2);
  });
```